# How do I make demand_callback consider a variable that depends on to_node in ortools?

Tags: python, logic, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm solving a vehicle routing problem using google ortools, and i need the demand_calback function take into consideration the time_visits (that depends on from_node and it's working) and the displacement between two nodes (that depends on from_node and to_node).

The problem is that the demand_callback function doesn't accept another parameter besides from_node, so i can't call to_node (and as consequence i can't consider the displacement time).

My code is:

```
# Add Capacity constraint.
def demand_callback(from_index):
   """Returns the demand of the node."""
   # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
   from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
   '''Creates callback to get demands at each location.'''
   _time_visits = data['time_visits']
   return _time_visits[from_node]
```

And I would like the code to look like this:

```
 def demand_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the demand of the node."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)

    '''Creates callback to get demands at each location.'''
    _time_visits = data['time_visits']
    _displacements = data['matrix_displacement'][from_node]

    result = _time_visits[from_node] + _displacements[from_node][to_node]
    return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example, for demand dimension we advertise the use of unary callback.
Here, it seems you want to use a regular callback...

```py
def demand_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the demand of the node."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)

    '''Creates callback to get demands at each location.'''
    _time_visits = data['time_visits']
    _displacements = data['matrix_displacement'][from_node]

    result = _time_visits[from_node] + _displacements[from_node][to_node]
    return result
```

Then register it using `RegisterTransitCallback()` instead of `RegisterUnaryTransitCallback()`.

```py
demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(demand_callback)
```

Comment: This being said, callbacks are stateless. You cannot check the value of an integer variable during the evaluation. This is forbidden, and actually enforced because most of the time, the result of the callback is cached.

Comment: Hi! i tried that but not worked. I solved by another method.

But anyway, thank you!!!